# What are the most common viewport sizes for laptops and desktops?

Tags: responsive

I'm making my Web Page responsive. To do this I use the "Responsive Web Design" tool provided by the Firefox Inspector.

The problem I find is that I can test the layout on different viewport sizes on phones but there is no option to choose viewport sizes for desktops, laptops and tablets (only one for iPad). So I would like to know what the usual sizes are for these devices, so that I can include them in the size field provided by Firefox Inspector and check my Web Page.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have found [this](https://gs.statcounter.com/screen-resolution-stats/desktop/worldwide) to be a great tool.

This is the current desktop-only data globally as of August 2022:

| Resolution | Percentage |
| --- | --- |
| 1920x1080 | 22.63% |
| 1366x768 | 17.42% |
| 1536x864 | 11.13% |
| 1280x720 | 6.05% |
| 1440x900 | 5.63% |
| 1600x900 | 3.69% |

Comment: Thanks Jameel. These are Screen sizes, not Viewport sizes. I am not sure but for media queries the viewport size is the most important thing, rigth???

Comment: For the sake of what you're trying to do, they're synonymous. It sounds like you're focusing on adaptive development vs. responsive development. Adaptive development focuses on specific breakpoints/viewports/devices, whereas truly responsive is ensuring things look/function great on all devices. I'd encourage you to focus less on exact target viewport sizes, and instead, ensure what you're building looks and functions great on ALL sizes.

Comment: Thanks Jameel, for your comment. I have seen that the traditional way to check if a Web Page is Responsive is to drag the right edge of the Page and reduce or enlarge its width. But for example: My monitor is 1920px X 919px. I have reduced the width and applied the necessary media queries. But as a last step, I want to check how it looks at specific viewport sizes. For example, my laptop is 1088px X 453px; that is, a height less than half, where the Web Page looks very different. So, I think it's good to check different heights. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Good *Responsive Web Design* is not only optimised for some—often arbitrarily chosen— device sizes. It’s the space between the extremes that’s interesting and important.

[Ethan Marcotte calls that Seams and edges](https://ethanmarcotte.com/wrote/responsive-design-seams-edges/)

On larger screens, window managers allow **windows to be resized to any size**.

My hypothesis is that the larger the screen, the less likely windows are opened in full screen. The screen resolution becomes quite a worthless information.

### Width and height are on a continuum, how would you determine “the most common sizes”?

You would need to reduce the variance of width and height to distinct groups, to arrive at something useful.

Most designers only take the *viewport width* into account for their interfaces (instead of f.e. the device orientation or ratio).

Therefore, you could reduce the set of viewport widths to multiples of 100. A viewport width of 687 might go in *group 600—700*. Only then can you produce a histogram that might help take design decisions.

I created a statistic once on the ratio of the viewport width and height. Interestingly, the desktop visitors of our communication agency website mainly open their windows almost square!